# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) using stat

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I need that my program show information about a file. So here's my code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct stat fileStat;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <pathname>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

   if (stat(argv[1], &fileStat) == -1) {
        exit(1);
   }
    printf("ID ", fileStat.st_uid);

    printf("Dydis: \t\t%d bytes\n" + fileStat.st_size);
}
```

But I get this error

```
Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Voting to close because this question is not findable by anyone with the same problem and adds no value to the community.

Comment: So how I need to fo formulize my question?

Comment: No, I don't think there's anything to be done here.

Comment: Another answer is: why is gcc not returning a warning (`pedantic` flags on) when using `printf("%d"+1);` but it does with  `printf("%d");` ?

Comment: @user3334375 There is not really anything wrong with the question. There is just a SO policy saying that questions where the problem was related to a simple typo should get closed, as they have no value to future readers. So don't freak out if this question ends up "on hold" eventually :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your code

```
printf("Dydis: \t\t%d bytes\n" + fileStat.st_size);
```

to

```
printf("Dydis: \t\t%d bytes\n", fileStat.st_size);
                              ^
                              |
                          notice this change
```

Reference: As per `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.3, the syntax is,

> `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`